# iOS CPU Profile: Why might this thread be sucking up 99.9% CPU?

Tags: ios, multithreading, xcode-instruments

Sometimes when I load a table view, and I'm performing no activity intentionally except letting the table view show, I'll wait a few seconds and then my CPU usage shoots up. How can I find the cause?

[image]

Comment: I would guess that it's in an "infinite" loop.  In this case likely because storage has gotten mucked up, though possibly because you have somehow describe a circular data structure that's now being navigated.

Comment: I think we'll need more details (iOS version and so fourth). And it's probably and infinite loop as @HotLicks said.

Comment: Invert the call tree and try finding the offending method/function. Sounds like a UIKit/drawing issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why might this thread be sucking up 99.9% CPU?

I don't know. But here are some thoughts:

1. The responsible library is `UIKit`. So it seems that some user interface code is broken.
2. A function named `FreeContextStack` is running for a long time.
3. `pthread_once` and `pthread_getspecific` take a considerable amount of time. These functions are fast, so they have to run **very** often.
4. They are part of `GetContextStack` and `PopContext`

It seems that in your code there is some sort of "context" stack being pushed—but not popped. I'd look for occurrences of `UIGraphicsPushContext` or `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` without their closing counterparts.

But I might be totally off and those functions are not part of graphics context code.

Comment: Eg, it might be that context A is a child of context B which is a child of context A....

Comment: Exactly! I was missing `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` and `CGImageRelease(imageRef)`.

Comment: I was seeing the same thing. Had the same problem. Thank you internet smarty man!

Comment: I have this issue, but nowhere in my project do we not end the image context. Does anybody have any other possible solutions? It is also random. It is not reproducible and happens on a variety of random views occasionally....

Answer (score 1):

Its possible you're not ending your `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`

I solved the same  by adding `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` after use.

Comment: (Rudi, you showed up in the low quality post queue because your answer looked like "I have same problem"; so I changed the phrasing a little - hope its ok with you)