# CPU Usage spike in the iOS application - pthread_tsd_cleanup

Tags: ios, pthreads, cpu-usage

we are facing a huge spike in the CPU usage and have observed it happens only when we start getting this thread in the profiler pthread_tsd_cleanup

Screenshot attached[image]

Any idea of what we could have done wrong? or to look into?

Comment: I think this could be relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940174/ios-cpu-profile-why-might-this-thread-be-sucking-up-99-9-cpu